# Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'

Tags: android

Here is full message from log:
Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         file:/C:/Users/Anatoly/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom
>         file:/C:/Users/Anatoly/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.jar
>         file:/C:/Users/Anatoly/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom
>         file:/C:/Users/Anatoly/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.jar
>         file:/C:/Users/Anatoly/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom
>         file:/C:/Users/Anatoly/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.jar
>         file:/C:/android/AndroidStudio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom
>         file:/C:/android/AndroidStudio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.jar
>     Required by:
>         project :app

My **gradle-wrapper.properties**

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

My **build.gradle of project**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Gradle 4.1 and higher include support for Google's Maven repo using
        // the google() method. And you need to include this repo to download
        // Android plugin 3.0.0 or higher.
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

My **build.gradle of app**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.foodrobot.test2"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: I can't start Android studio project, I get this error:  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

Answer (score 14):

I modified project level **`/gradle.build`**

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
```

to:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"}
```

in files:

```
platforms/android/build.gradle
```

Comment: Ionic 3: This solution works, also you need to place the following code in your `platforms/android/app/build.gradle` file:- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ionic-run-android-com-android-support-conflicting-v26-alpha1-and-v25-3-1/91826/4

Answer (score 2):

add google() in repositories at project level and click Sync Now and error will be gone. as

**build.gradle(Project:XXX)**

```
repositories {
   google()//new 
   jcenter()
}
```

Comment: Take a closer look. In the question he already has google() in the repositories.

Comment: I did not had google. This helped solve my problem. :P

Answer (score 1):

Rename the gradle.properties file to xgradle.properties and try:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

It will work fine.